# Difference between v1, v2 and v3 in https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

Tags: android, node.js, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to authenticate a user on Android via [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) to get the account name, grab the token via GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), app, scopes), and then send the token to my NodeJS back-end server to verify

I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159782/how-can-i-decode-a-google-oauth-2-0-jwt-openid-connect-in-a-node-app) great stackoverflow question on how to decode it, cache the key id (KID) so it's not doing a round trip every time, etc. (haven't implemented this part yet, but sort of played around with it) My only question is: what's the difference between the following googleapis certs:

- www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
- www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs
- www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

The KID on each version are identical, but the content is overtly different. Why? v2 and v3 seem to be almost identical except that v2 has an "==" appended at the end of the value of property 'n'

Most importantly, which version do I use?

I think these certs are called JSON Web Keys (JWK). I've also read the term 'x5c' What is that?

PS: The token I'm getting on my nodejs from my android app is:

```
{
 "iss": "accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "SOME_LONG_NUMBER_THAT_I_DONT_KNOW_IF_SHOULD_SHOW",
 "azp": "SERVER_CLIENT_ID",
 "email": "ANDROID_USER_EMAIL",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "aud": "ANDROID_CLIENT_ID",
 "iat": "SOME_NUMBER",
 "exp": "SOME_NUMBER",
 "alg": "RS256",
 "kid": "e53139984bd36d2c230552441608cc0b5179487a"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Version 1](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs) appears to be a basic JSON mapping of key ids to certificate strings. I don't have any inside information, but I would speculate that this is a simple "home-grown" format that somebody at Google made up as an easy way to distribute their public keys.

As you have noted, [versions 2](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs) and [3](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) are distributed in the JSON Web Key (JWK) format. This format is defined in a formal specification, [RFC 7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517), which lays out exactly how to structure a JSON response representing cryptographic keys.

As for the difference between v2 and v3, it looks like v2 included [trailing equal signs as padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) and in v3 they've simply stripped those off.

> I've also read the term 'x5c' What is that?

In [the specification](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-key-12.html#x5cDef), 'x5c' is defined as an optional parameter for specifying a list of cryptographic certificates that together form a ["chain of trust"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust) that would allow a client application to validate the key by verifying each certificate in turn and following the chain back to a known, trusted [root certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate).

> Most importantly, which version do I use?

If possible, I would suggest using the most-current version. But as long as the keys themselves are identical, it probably doesn't matter very much.