# Enable Google API for "googleapis.com/auth/userinfo"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am developing a Google Chrome Extension. I would like to be able to access the user profile info, using the data from these endpoints:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo

I don't seem to have access to these resources. From my web searches, it looks like I may need to enable a library API in the Google Developers Console. But I looked there and cannot find an appropriate API to enable. Does anyone know which API I should enable?

Comment: In the case of use of ``https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo``, it is not required to enable API related to this. You can use the endpoint by access token retrieved from OAuth2 process. When you use this, please include ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`` to the scopes. If this information was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is an additional information. As a test, I used it without enabling all APIs. The sample curl command is ``curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###" "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"``. I confirmed that it worked. The scope of token is only ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile``. About the endpoint, ``https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`` and ``https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo`` return the same information.

Comment: do you know what the difference is between the two urls in the OP?

Comment: About ``userinfo``, it returns the same information. Also v3 is the same. It seems that about the endpoints except for ``userinfo``, there is the difference between versions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277898/difference-between-v1-v2-and-v3-in-https-www-googleapis-com-oauth2-v3-certs

Answer (score 3):

You will need to at least add the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` as per mentioned.

Then you can use the `oauth2` apis just like how would you use `sheets`, `calendar` etc.

In nodejs, it'd be something like this:

```js
    const { google } = require('googleapis')
    const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      keys.web.client_id,
      keys.web.client_secret,
      keys.web.redirect_uris[0]
    )
    // get the tokens from google
    auth.credentials = tokens
    const oauth2 = google.oauth2({ version: 'v2', auth })
    const userinfo = await oauth2.userinfo.get()
    console.log(userinfo)
```

The api is documented here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/oauth2/interfaces/Schema$Userinfo.html#info. There are also some examples in the source code there.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just user's email-address for auth etc., you have to enable Google's [Plus API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/plus.googleapis.com/), **not** the G**-*****d `People API` which is mentioned everywhere in the Google Cloud API docs.

Also, you need to mention the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`, **not** the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` one.

p.s. It's an old question, yet unanswered. Possibly, you've already solved it. I'm posting it for people from the future, or just for my future self.

Comment: You should know that Google+ related APIs are being shut down in January '19. More at [Google blog](https://www.blog.google/technology/safety-security/expediting-changes-google-plus/).

Comment: if google+ is become shutdown... wouldn't safe if we use gmail api?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve data from these endpoints if you have an access token from the user. First, you have to get an access token by letting the user login using **google login API**. Then retrieve the data from the following link.
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=PUT_YOUR_USER'S_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE