# Android Kotlin - Google Credential Manager - get user ID

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, android-credential-manager

```
if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
    try {

        val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
            .createFrom(credential.data)

        val personToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
        val personId = googleIdTokenCredential.id
        val displayName = googleIdTokenCredential.displayName
        val personPhoto = googleIdTokenCredential.profilePictureUri

    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
        Log.d("pikaboo", "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
    }
}
```

`googleIdTokenCredential.id` gives me the email address, is this a bug?

The code for the old Sign In was:

```
val acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this@GoogleLogin)
if (acct != null) {
    val displayName = acct.displayName
    val personGivenName = acct.givenName
    val personFamilyName = acct.familyName
    val personId = acct.id
    val personPhoto = acct.photoUrl

    var photo = ""
    if(personPhoto != null){
        photo = personPhoto.toString()
    }

    sendToServer(personId!!, photo, displayName, personGivenName, personFamilyName)
}
```

and `acct.id` gave me an id like `113755066377078777777`

I have many users which are associated with an id like this, what the hell is wrong with google? How can I get the normal id instead of email address with the new Credential Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question on whether that is a bug or not, the answer is no, that is not a bug. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/android-credential-manager/android/reference/com/google/android/libraries/identity/googleid/GoogleIdTokenCredential#getId()) clearly states, that field returns the email address of the user:

> the email address associated with user's Google Account.

In order to get to the "id" that you want, you'd need to look inside the ID Token that is captured by `personToken` in your snippet. The ID Token has a number of fields in a JWT format (basically JSON) and is best to be parsed by the caller to extract the information that is desired. You are probably interested in the "sub" field there, see [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#id-contents) for more details. Note that your personToken is a signed-JWT and is Base64-encoded; you would need to decode that (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159782/how-can-i-decode-a-google-oauth-2-0-jwt-openid-connect-in-a-node-app) post for example) in order to get the payload that you're interested in, and also would need to verify that (possibly on your server side) it was signed by Google, for security measures.

Finally, as a side note, let me mention that the nature of `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount` is very different from the Credential Manager's API that you had mentioned; the former was used to obtain the information about a Google account that was previously used to sign into an app on the same device while the latter is for the purpose of signing into an app.

Comment: I know that it's not actually a bug but in the old sign in it was an id now it's email address, it's weird. Ok maybe it's something a bit different, but at least they should keep the old working stuff instead of deprecating it and focus on stuff that really need optimization, like RecyclerView, it's very slow compared to ios LazyVStack when displaying images and videos.

Comment: Ok I'm obtaining the sub by extracting it from the token server side using curl to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=tok, it's probably also way more secure to send the token to the server instead of only the sub :D Thanks

Comment: @ali-naddaf sorry for spoiling this question but since I was planning to use the new Credential Manager's API, is there something similar to `getLastSignedInAccount`?

To give you some more context of what I am trying to achieve: I need to use Drive API to create a custom backup solution in "appDataFolder", and that requires authentication (and not authorization as far as I understood from docs). Therefore the user must sign in, then the app has to use the `GoogleSignInAccount` and pass it to Drive API. 

So is that doable with the new Credential Manager's API or I have to use the old one?

Comment: Actually, for accessing appDataFolder using the Drive APIs, you do need authorization (there is a scope involved which I believe is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"). So you can't just use CredentialManager to achieve that, you'd need to use our Authorization APIs. Hope that helps; if you have more questions on that, please do let me know.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response @ali-naddaf.
From the scope codes matrix here:  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth the `appData` which I only need to backup states "provides the smallest scope of authorization access and only requires basic app verification". 
Now if I understand correctly and from what I see from the docs, the authorization is executed by creating a `GoogleAccountCredential` with the `usingOAuth2(Context context, Collection scopes)` and then in the `GoogleAccountCredential` we pass the email with the `setSelectedAccountName`.

Comment: The GoogleAccountCredential is later passed to Drive.Builder. 

Therefore, why not executing the "basic app verification" with the CredentialManager, then retrieve the account data from the `CustomCredential` -> `TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL` and finally use it to authorize Drive service? And if what I  am saying is correct so far, then I come back to the previous question. Does the `CredentialManager` have a similar way to `getLastSignedInAccount` so I don't have to sign in every time I launch the app?